# RAID migration w/ MegaRAID SAS Raid controller

Tags: raid, lvm, megaraid

I have a workstation with 8 drive bays and a MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 raid controller. 5 of the 8 bays are populated, and it is configured as a RAID5.

I need to expand my disk-space, and putting in 3 more identical drives wont cut it.

What I was thinking about doing is populating the open 3 bays with 3 new disks, configuring that as a RAID6, then cloning the system from the 5-drive RAID5 to the 3-drive RAID6. Then remove the 5-old drives, then put in new-drives and expand the 3-drive RAID.

**What I've done so far;**

1) I put in 3 new 8tb drives into the empty bays, and configured the raid 6 (wanted to make sure my raid card would support two independent raids).

**Questions;**

2) I have this set up as an LVM, and think that will make it easier, and all I need to do is create a new pv, shrink the current vg to a matching size, then add the old vg to the new pv;
https://askubuntu.com/questions/161279/how-do-i-move-my-lvm-250-gb-root-partition-to-a-new-120gb-hard-disk

3) What do I do about boot partitions? On my current raid5 I have;

/boot/efi   (fat32)

/boot       (ext4)

Can I just clone these partitions in gparted to the new raid6, then change the boot location in the boot menu? Do I need to change UUIDs?

4) Anything else?

Comment: Hi, your question is attracting close votes (not sure why). Are you able to clarify the exact problem you need help with? Also take a moment to look at [ask] to see if there is anything you could do to improve the responses.